# entity inheritance and discriminatorColumns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hibernate-annotations

I am trying to test some DAOs.

I have Entity (and table) named `Nomination`, it has some properties:

```
@Entity(name = "Nomination")
@Table(name = "NOMINATION")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="CATEGORY_CODE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 1)

public class Nomination extends AuditableEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "NOM_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true,
        nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Transient
protected NominationType type = null;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "PERIOD_ID", referencedColumnName = "PERIOD_ID")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
        org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE})
private NomPeriod period = null;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_CODE")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
        org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE})
private Category category = null;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "NOMINATOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "EMP_ID")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
        org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE})
private Employee nominator = null;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "STATUS_ID", referencedColumnName = "STATUS_ID")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
        org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE})
private Status status = null;

//more after this line
```

Now I have 4 different types of Nomination (idea, team, success, and coworker nominations) and 4 different tables(nomination, team_nom, idea_nom, success_nom). One (NOMINATION) has the common columns. This coincides with my first type of Nomination called `CoworkerNom`. There is no separate table for this one, since it only needs what's listed in the NOMINATION table. The other 3 Nominations are: `TeamNom`, `SuccessNom`, and `IdeaNom`. These have their own tables as they have additional data, and so they also have their own Entities. For example:

```
@Entity(name = "IdeaNom")
@Table(name = "IDEA_NOM")
@DiscriminatorValue("I")

public class IdeaNom extends Nomination {

@Column(name = "PURPOSE_INC", insertable = true, updatable = true,
        nullable = true)
private Boolean purposeIncrease;

@Column(name = "PURPOSE_SIMPLIFY", insertable = true, updatable = true,
        nullable = true)
private Boolean purposeSimplify;

//more after this line
```

This structure applies to `SuccessNom` and `TeamNom`.

I am having problems understanding how to do this, but for now I have done some DAOs and am trying to test them out. However I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: 

com.dev.test.data.entity.SuccessNom column: CATEGORY_CODE (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:698)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass.validate(SingleTableSubclass.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 54 more
```

First of all, CATEGORY_CODE is the discriminator... but it should be able to be writable. Hopefully you guys will be able to help me out once more.

Edit: this is my schema

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to map the discriminator column, map it with `insert="false" update="false"`. Hibernate considers it declared once, and it is not writable - it can only be managed by hibernate. Also, it's a bit odd to join on that column.

Comment: I'm not joining on that column, I am joining at ID - my impression is that it would "discriminate" as the name says and attribute a row with an x category_code to the specific child entity. Perhaps I should have stated that first. I will edit and show my schema, hopefully it will be clearer then.

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_CODE", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_CODE")

Comment: So you're saying that I should just remove that and let the child entities handle which Category_code to set? I think I know what you're saying (maybe?) but I wrote the joins on main entity Nomination before I found out about the discriminator annotations (just found out today because its the last set of tables I'm testing DAOs for and they simply weren't working).

Comment: I think my question is, when inserting a new "nomination" will the category to which the particular nomination belongs to be written there in that field? I'm seeing this way too much like a newbie here, sorry.

Comment: sorry, quite a headache here so I can't plunge into your scenario, but the general rule is that you should not do anything with the discriminator column.

Comment: you said that it would be managed by hibernate, which sort of answers my question but how will the Nomination entities make the connection my Category entity - or is this not needed?

Comment: anyway thank you, that fixed my error - i commented the whole attribute and it worked fine. I will post my next question as separate...